# Can GEOMETRY_COLUMNS reside in a different SCHEMA?

Tags: geoserver

I'm using a table generating tool that cannot create tables in "dbo" for SQL Server so I'm generating GIS.GEOMETRY_COLUMNS instead of dbo.GEOMETRY_COLUMNS and I'm wondering if there is a configuration option in GeoServer to allow me to set GIS.GEOMETRY_COLUMNS as the spatial registry.

Comment: Based on the code I'm seeing on github (https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/search?q=geometry_columns) the answer seems to be no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a GeoTools/GeoServer JDBC datastore is associated with a single schema.

**Update** from a scan of the source code it looks like you can use `schema.table` or just `name` in that parameter. I've never tried that but it looks like it should work.